# XSLT copy starting from certain node

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I want to move a part of an XML file into another node using XSLT.
I only want to move everything starting a certain node.
It will be best to explain through an example.

This would be the input XML (it's just a sample)

```
<Messages>
  <Message>
    <Header>
        <Name>Message Content 1</Name>
    </Header>
    <Info1>
        <Description>blabla</Description>
    </Info1>
    <Info2>
        <Name>Test</Name>
        <Description>blabla</Description>
    </Info2>
    ... Possible more nodes (with random names)
    <Header>
        <Name>Message Content Summary</Name>
    </Header>
    <Info1>
        <Total>blablabla</Total>
    </Info1>
    ... Possible more nodes (with random names)
  </Message>
</Messages>
```

I would like to get the following output:

```
<Messages>
  <Message>
    <Header>
        <Name>Message Content 1</Name>
    </Header>
    <Info1>
        <Description>blabla</Description>
    </Info1>
    <Info2>
        <Name>Test</Name>
        <Description>blabla</Description>
    </Info2>
    ... Possible more nodes (with random names)
  </Message>
  <MessageSummary>
    <Header>
        <Name>Message Content Summary</Name>
    </Header>
    <Info1>
        <Total>blablabla</Total>
    </Info1>
    ... Possible more nodes (with random names)
  </MessageSummary>
</Messages>
```

So I want to move everything starting from the last occurance of the node "Header" into a seperate node "MessageSummary".

Is there any way I can accomplish this using XSLT 1.0?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So when you're at the context of the input `Message` element, you want to put any element that has at least one `Header` after it into the output `Message` and everything else inside `MessageSummary`.  You can distinguish these two cases as `*[following-sibling::Header]` and `*[not(following-sibling::Header)]`, so if we start from a standard identity transformation we end up with

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:output indent="yes" />

  <!-- identity template - copies everything as-is unless overridden -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Message">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[following-sibling::Header]" />
    </xsl:copy>
    <MessageSummary>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(following-sibling::Header)]" />
    </MessageSummary>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you have other elements named `Message` in the "random names" section you may wish to make this template more specific, e.g.

```
  <xsl:template match="Messages/Message">
```

so it only catches the elements you really want.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the suggestion. I modified it a bit so the first copy selects *[following-sibling::Header[1]] ==> all items under the first header need to be copied. The second copy selects: *[not(following-sibling::Header[2])] ==> All items under the second header need to be copied to the summary node. It seems to work fine :)

Comment: @Rise_against that won't quite do what you describe, because numerical predicates on the sibling axes count siblings - `*[not(following- sibling::Header[2])]` finds all elements that have at least two headers after them, so the elements before the second-to-last header, not the second one necessarily. If you want to use the second header as the cut off point then you need something like `Header[2]/preceding-sibling::*` for the first section and `Header[2] | Header[2]/following-sibling::*` for the second.

Comment: Hi Ian, you are correct! Forget my last remark, your solution works fine! It was my fault that it didn't work at first (made some typos in the XSLT). But after correction, it works as expected. Thank you again for the help!